# Is rowid concept is there in AS400 like in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Irrespective of whether the table has duplicate records, primary key whatever I wanted to uniquely identify each row in As400.
In Oracle there is rowid concept , there irrespective of whether the table has duplicate records or whatever there is unique rowid to each rows ,so I can fetch only that particular record using rowid.
is there such kind of thing present in AS400?

I did some search related to row number in db2 AS400, but thats not meet the above requirement.

Comment: Why do you think, that the RRN function doesn't meet your requirement?

Comment: I tried in this db2 editor https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9pQuWw5  , but I am getting error while using rrn function.  Can you help me out in this..  - @MarkBarinstein

Comment: You must know, that Db2 for IBM i (iSeries, OS/400) is different product from Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows which is used at the link you provided. There is really no [RRN](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-rrn) function in Db2 for LUW, but it does exist in Db2 for IBM i.

Comment: @PavanRaga Please don't just say "there's an error", this doesn't help in diagnosing. Give us an example of what exactly you do and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: tnx for the info . RRN value can be change ryt? when reorg operation or deletion operation has done? - @MarkBarinstein

Comment: After reorg - yes in all cases. After delete the same value returned by RRN may be "occupied" by another row inserted after such a delete depending on the table property mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique identifier for AS400 Database if there is no primary key / unique key / composite key defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74599271/unique-identifier-for-as400-database-if-there-is-no-primary-key-unique-key-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. DB2 on OS/400 allows unique identification of a given record at a given point in time only by RRN. (Unless your database definition used unique primary key, that is.)

As pointed out in answers to your [former request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74599271/unique-identifier-for-as400-database-if-there-is-no-primary-key-unique-key-c/74599693?noredirect=1#comment131687320_74599693), the RRN is to be considered **temporary**! An RRN is always referring to an unique record, but a record's RRN can change:

- when you reorganize a PF (table) through `rgzpfm`,
- when you delete records,
- when you add records, and `REUSEDLT(*YES)` is in effect — which is the default.

Thus it's important to realize the *temporary nature* of RRN to record association.

Comment: @PavanRaga Also, why do you start yet another question when your original question is still not marked as solved? Please don't spam Stackoverflow.