# Is there a ROWID concept in AS400 database

Tags: ibm-midrange

How can we uniquely identify a record in AS400 if primary key/unique key/composite key is not defined? Is there a ROWID pseudo column in AS400 similar to Oracle?

If yes, how can we retrieve all row values along with ROWID values with a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before. See

- [Unique identifier for AS400 Database if there is no primary key /
  unique key / composite key defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74599271/unique-identifier-for-as400-database-if-there-is-no-primary-key-unique-key-c)
- [Is rowid concept is there in AS400 like in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609131/is-rowid-concept-is-there-in-as400-like-in-oracle).

When you enter a new question, the Web-UI offers you similar questions. Apparently you ignored these.

Comment: As long as there's at least one answer with an upvote on another question, you can vote to close a question as a duplicate.